# Rate a Content using LIferay API

Tags: api, liferay, rating, rate

I have a custom Portlet that shows some Contents of Liferay and I have to be able to rate those contents.
I recover the information of the ratings of this content for

```
RatingsStats currentRate = RatingsStatsLocalServiceUtil.getStats(JournalArticle.class.getName(),
                    article.getResourcePrimKey());
```

but the crazy thing is, when i update any field of this table like `currentRate.getTotalEntries()`, the data is no updated.

I attached the full method and logs.

```
article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticle(primKey);           
RatingsStats currentRate = RatingsStatsLocalServiceUtil.getStats(JournalArticle.class.getName(),
                    article.getResourcePrimKey());
LOG.debug("ratingStats entrada a editar: " + currentRate.getStatsId());
LOG.debug("currentRate.getTotalEntries() BEFORE:  " + currentRate.getTotalEntries());
currentRate.setTotalEntries(currentRate.getTotalEntries()+1);
LOG.debug("currentRate.getTotalEntries() AFTER:  " + currentRate.getTotalEntries());
```

The LOG is the following:

```
11:35:18,634 DEBUG [AgregadoresContenidosController:262] ratingStats entrada a editar: 110551
11:35:18,634 DEBUG [AgregadoresContenidosController:263] currentRate.getTotalEntries() BEFORE:  0
11:35:18,635 DEBUG [AgregadoresContenidosController:265] currentRate.getTotalEntries() AFTER:  1
```

And everytime i getTotalEntries, the value is '0', is not updated.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I thought the update on the Database will be automatically with the method's set, but i was wrong.

The following line is needed in order to make the update in DDBB.

```
RatingsStatsLocalServiceUtil.updateRatingsStats(currentRate);
```

Doubt solved :)